# How can I get transform matrix for QQuickItem?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I worked for a long time with `QGraphicsItem` and it has `transform()` function. Now I wont to do same thing with `QQuickItem` but unfortunately it misses `transform()`. So my question - how can I get transform matrix for `QQuickItem`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually the `QQuickItem` provides the `transform()` method, however it returns the list of all transformations assigned to given item. It is because multiple transformations can be assigned to a single `Item`. The return type of `QQuickItem::transform` is `QQmlListProperty<QQuickTransform>` — it is a wrapper to QML `list<Transform>` type (see [documentation for Item](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#transform-prop)). It can be iterated over, yielding `QQuickTransform *` elements. `QQuickTransform` is a base class for a transformation that provides a virtual method `applyTo` taking a `QMatrix4x4 *` argument and applying the transformation upon it.

The QML allows instantiating several `QQuickTransform` subclasses (for translation, rotation and scale) and user is allowed to defined custom transformations (eg. for skew).

To obtain a single transformation matrix you need, you have to start with identity matrix and sequentially apply all the transformations of given `QQuickItem`.

```
QMatrix4x4 transformOfItem(QQuickItem *item)
{
    QQmlListProperty transformations = item->transform();

    const int count = transformations.count(&transformations);

    // Prepare result structure, it will be default-initialized to be an identity matrix
    QMatrix4x4 transformMatrix;

    // Apply sequentially all transformation from the item
    for(int i = 0; i applyTo(&transformMatrix);
    }

    return transformMatrix;
}
```

Note that the function returns a tranformation matrix as `QMatrix4x4` — it is more than old `QTransform` that was based on 3x3 transformation matrix, so it cannot be converted without loss. If you want, you may use `QMatrix4x4::toAffine` to get the `QMatrix` (3x3) and use it to create `QTransform` object. However, if your `QQuickItem` transformations contain non-affinic elements, they will be lost.

### Edit

There's one more thing to note: the method I posted works only for transformations defined by assigning to `transform` property. It does not check for `scale` and `rotation` properties. If you use them, you should check their values with appropriate `QQuickItem` methods and adjust returned matrix to include these two additional tranformations.

Comment: Thanks, @Michał W. Urbańczyk.I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a correct solution, based on the code provided by Michael earlier, but fixed to work actually, so you don't have to spend 20 minutes figuring out how to use QQmlListProperty

```
QMatrix4x4 YourQQuickItem::get_model_matrix() {
    QMatrix4x4 result;

    // Compose model matrix from our transform properties in the QML
    QQmlListProperty<QQuickTransform> transformations = transform();
    const int count = transformations.count(&transformations);
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        QQuickTransform *transform = transformations.at(&transformations, i);
        transform->applyTo(&result);
    }

    return result;
}
```

In my use case I use this to get the model matrix for my object, then multiply together with view and projection matrixes to calculate the model-view-projection matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The [QSGTransformNode](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsgtransformnode.html) class implements transformations in the scene graph. In `updatePaintNode` function, argument `updatePaintNodeData` provides a pointer to the `QSGTransformNode` associated with this `QQuickItem`.

```
QSGNode *MyQuickItem::updatePaintNode(QSGNode *oldNode, QQuickItem::UpdatePaintNodeData *data)
{
     QSGTransformNode *transformNode = data->transformNode;
     qDebug() << transformNode->matrix();
```

Comment: it seems that I've asked my question in incorrect way. So I created a new one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28540057/keep-position-of-qquickitem-while-transformation-although-origin-point-was-chang