# My OpenGL QQuickItem won't have the size I want

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qml, glsl

I'm drawing with OpenGL on Qtquick and no matter what size I put on my `OpenGlVideoQtQuick` on QML, it always occupies the entire space of the window. I want to be able to control its size.

I created this minimal example which draws a green screen with OpenGL. I should be able to control the size of QQuickItem and thus control the size of the green screen to occupy, for example, 1/4 of the screen.

You can see that I even tried (and commented) the `setWidth` and `setHeight` methods on the QQuickItem. It won't work.

You can see a minimal working and compilable example here: https://github.com/lucaszanella/openglqtquickexample/tree/4de3ec1535eb40c31788512a027c1e86f76d4090

**How do I control the size of my QQuickItem?**

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import OpenGLComponents 1.0
Item {
    width: 1280
    height: 720
    OpenGlVideoQtQuick {
        width: 640
        height: 480

    }
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QPushButton> 
#include <QGuiApplication>

#include <QtQuick/QQuickView>

#include "OpenGlVideoQtQuick.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath("./");
    qmlRegisterType<OpenGlVideoQtQuick>("OpenGLComponents", 1, 0, "OpenGlVideoQtQuick");

    QQuickView view;
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

OpenGlVideoQtQuick.cpp:

```
#include "OpenGlVideoQtQuick.h"

#define GET_STR(x) #x
#define A_VER 3
#define T_VER 4

//Simple shader. Outpus the same location as input, I guess
const char *vString2 = GET_STR(
    attribute vec4 vertexIn;
    attribute vec2 textureIn;
    varying vec2 textureOut;
    void main(void)
    {
        gl_Position = vertexIn;
        textureOut = textureIn;
    }
);

const char *tString2 = GET_STR(
    varying vec2 textureOut;
    uniform sampler2D tex_y;
    uniform sampler2D tex_u;
    uniform sampler2D tex_v;
    void main(void)
    {
        vec3 yuv;
        vec3 rgb;
        yuv.x = texture2D(tex_y, textureOut).r;
        yuv.y = texture2D(tex_u, textureOut).r - 0.5;
        yuv.z = texture2D(tex_v, textureOut).r - 0.5;
        rgb = mat3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
            0.0, -0.39465, 2.03211,
            1.13983, -0.58060, 0.0) * yuv;
        gl_FragColor = vec4(rgb, 1.0);
    }

);

OpenGlVideoQtQuick::OpenGlVideoQtQuick():
    openGlVideoQtQuickRenderer(nullptr)
{
    connect(this, &QQuickItem::windowChanged, this, &OpenGlVideoQtQuick::handleWindowChanged);

    update();
    //setWidth(640);
    //setHeight(480);
    //width=640
    //height=480
}

void OpenGlVideoQtQuick::handleWindowChanged(QQuickWindow *win)
{
    if (win) {
        connect(win, &QQuickWindow::beforeSynchronizing, this, &OpenGlVideoQtQuick::sync, Qt::DirectConnection);
        win->setClearBeforeRendering(false);
    }
}

void OpenGlVideoQtQuick::update()
{
    if (window())
        window()->update();
}


OpenGlVideoQtQuickRenderer::~OpenGlVideoQtQuickRenderer()
{
    delete program;
}



void OpenGlVideoQtQuick::sync()
{
    if (!openGlVideoQtQuickRenderer) {
        openGlVideoQtQuickRenderer = new OpenGlVideoQtQuickRenderer();
        connect(window(), &QQuickWindow::beforeRendering, openGlVideoQtQuickRenderer, &OpenGlVideoQtQuickRenderer::render, Qt::DirectConnection);
        connect(window(), &QQuickWindow::afterRendering, this, &OpenGlVideoQtQuick::update, Qt::DirectConnection);
    }
}

static const GLfloat ver[] = {
    -1.0f,-1.0f,
     1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f,
     1.0f, 1.0f
};

static const GLfloat tex[] = {
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f
};


void OpenGlVideoQtQuickRenderer::render()
{
    if (this->firstRun) {
        std::cout << "Creating QOpenGLShaderProgram " << std::endl;
        this->firstRun = false;
        program = new QOpenGLShaderProgram();
        initializeOpenGLFunctions();

        std::cout << "Fragment Shader compilation: " << program->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, tString2) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Vertex Shader compilation: " << program->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, vString2) << std::endl;

        program->bindAttributeLocation("vertexIn",A_VER);
        program->bindAttributeLocation("textureIn",T_VER);
        std::cout << "program->link() = " << program->link() << std::endl;

        glGenTextures(3, texs);//TODO: ERASE THIS WITH glDeleteTextures
    }
    program->bind();

    //glViewport(50, 50, 50, 50);

    glVertexAttribPointer(A_VER, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, ver);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(A_VER);

    glVertexAttribPointer(T_VER, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, tex);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(T_VER);

    unis[0] = program->uniformLocation("tex_y");
    unis[1] = program->uniformLocation("tex_u");
    unis[2] = program->uniformLocation("tex_v");

    //Y
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[0]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, width, height, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    //U
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[1]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, width/2, height / 2, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    //V
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[2]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, width / 2, height / 2, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);



    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,4);

    program->disableAttributeArray(A_VER);
    program->disableAttributeArray(T_VER);
    program->release();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to scale the vertex coordinates in the vertex shader. This can be done by 4x4 matrix (`mat4`).
Declare a [uniform variable](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)) of type `mat4` and transform (multiply) the vertex coordainte by the matrix, before it is assigned to the clip space position `gl_Position`:

```c
attribute vec4 vertexIn;
attribute vec2 textureIn;

varying vec2 textureOut;

uniform mat4 u_transform;   

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = u_transform * vertexIn;
    textureOut = textureIn;
}
```

The value of the uniform has to be set in the program, by [`QOpenGLShaderProgram::setUniformValue()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglshaderprogram.html#setUniformValue-49). The type of the value has to be [`QMatrix4x4`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmatrix4x4.html).

e.g.

```cpp
program->bind();

QMatrix4x4 transform;
transform.setToIdentity();
transform.scale(0.25, 0.25);

program->setUniformValue("u_transform", transform);
```

Of course it is possible to use `glm::mat4`, too. It this case the value of the uniform has to be set by [`glUniformMatrix4fv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml):

```cpp
GLint transformLoc = program->uniformLocation("u_transform");

program->bind();

glm::mat4 transform(1.0f);
transform = glm::scale(transform, glm::vec3(0.25f, 0.25f, 1.0f));
glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLoc , 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(transform ));
```

Comment: I understand that this is a way to scale the image drawn on the screen, but it is the right way to impose a size for my QQuickItem? If I want it to be 640x480 I have to find a scale that will make it happen? Why I can't simply set a size for QQuickItem? It looks to me that this isn't the right way, but if it is, I'll certainly use it

Comment: for example, if I try to choose a x,y position for my QQuickItem, it will also not work. Do you know how OpenGl works in the background? It looks like it just ignores what a QQuickItem is and draws on a portion of the screen. This is horrible because what if I want my QQuickItem to be dragged and dropped by mouse? I think the right way would be to resize QQuickItem and it in turn resize the opengl. Can you understand me?

Comment: @LucasZanella Of course it is the right way. The size of the QQuickItem is useless, because you've set up vertex coordinates in the range -1.0, 1.0 (`GLfloat ver[] = { ..}`). The bottom left of the viewport is (-1, -1) and the top right (1, 1).  You have to change the vertex coordinates before you assign them to `gl_Position`. Either change the array or add a matrix. But you can get a transformation from the `QQuickItem`. See [How can I get transform matrix for QQuickItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28535528/how-can-i-get-transform-matrix-for-qquickitem)

Comment: can you explain why I end up with a small square on the left down corner? Also, the green screen is now in the middle and scaled right, but it's in the center of the screen. I think that I can also apply translation. So how to make it begin at (-1,1)?

Comment: sorry, I asked something too easy. I just saw that I can use .translate(). So, if I want to drag and drop a QQuickItem I have to map the mouse position to the translate() function? Is this the right way?

Comment: @LucasZanella Yes, it is.

Comment: Hi, since you talked about getting coordinates from QQuickItem, I've been trying to do it in my code. Could you give me a help? I've opened a bounty https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54902244/how-to-make-my-opengl-video-have-the-same-size-and-position-of-my-qquickitem