# How to make my OpenGL video have the same size and position of my QQuickItem?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qml

Following my latest question: [My OpenGL QQuickItem won't have the size I want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54872975/my-opengl-qquickitem-wont-have-the-size-i-want), I'm now trying,, instead of having an arbitrary size for my OpenGL video,  to fit it inside my QQuickItem.

I've heard that `QQuickItem::transform()` will give me a list of transformation matrices. I'm **assuming** that this list contains all the transformations needed to arrive at a square the size and position of my QQuickItem. <<<< Is this true? If so, the transformations are from what coordinates and viewport dimensions?

Given that as true, I've made the following minimal verifiable and compilable example that tries to make the green screen fit into the size of my QQuickItem. But currently, it just takes the entire screen.

I used the function `getModelMatrix()` that you can find below, to get all the transformations and make a matrix out of it. Then I apply these transformations to my vertex shader by doing

```
gl_Position = u_transform * vertexIn;
```

As I said, the result is a green screen. However, it has the same dimensions of my window, instead of having the dimensions 640x480 and x,y=0, as specified in `main.qml`

You can find a minimal compilable and verifiable example here: https://github.com/lucaszanella/openglqtquickexample/tree/88fe0092d663dd92c551c72acccd0bf058fe7e5b

**OpenGlVideoQtQuick.cpp:**

```
#include "OpenGlVideoQtQuick.h"

#define GET_STR(x) #x
#define A_VER 3
#define T_VER 4

//Simple shader. Outpus the same location as input, I guess
const char *vString2 = GET_STR(
    attribute vec4 vertexIn;
    attribute vec2 textureIn;
    varying vec2 textureOut;
    uniform mat4 u_transform;   
    void main(void)
    {
        gl_Position = u_transform * vertexIn;
        textureOut = textureIn;
    }
);

const char *tString2 = GET_STR(
    varying vec2 textureOut;
    uniform sampler2D tex_y;
    uniform sampler2D tex_u;
    uniform sampler2D tex_v;
    void main(void)
    {
        vec3 yuv;
        vec3 rgb;
        yuv.x = texture2D(tex_y, textureOut).r;
        yuv.y = texture2D(tex_u, textureOut).r - 0.5;
        yuv.z = texture2D(tex_v, textureOut).r - 0.5;
        rgb = mat3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
            0.0, -0.39465, 2.03211,
            1.13983, -0.58060, 0.0) * yuv;
        gl_FragColor = vec4(rgb, 1.0);
    }

);

OpenGlVideoQtQuick::OpenGlVideoQtQuick():
    openGlVideoQtQuickRenderer(nullptr)
{
    connect(this, &QQuickItem::windowChanged, this, &OpenGlVideoQtQuick::handleWindowChanged);

    update();
}

void OpenGlVideoQtQuick::handleWindowChanged(QQuickWindow *win)
{
    if (win) {
        connect(win, &QQuickWindow::beforeSynchronizing, this, &OpenGlVideoQtQuick::sync, Qt::DirectConnection);
        win->setClearBeforeRendering(false);
    }
}

QMatrix4x4 OpenGlVideoQtQuick::getModelMatrix() {
    QMatrix4x4 result;

    // Compose model matrix from our transform properties in the QML
    QQmlListProperty<QQuickTransform> transformations = transform();
    const int count = transformations.count(&transformations);
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        QQuickTransform *transform = transformations.at(&transformations, i);
        transform->applyTo(&result);
    }

    return result;
}


void OpenGlVideoQtQuick::update()
{
    if (window())
        window()->update();
}


OpenGlVideoQtQuickRenderer::~OpenGlVideoQtQuickRenderer()
{
    delete program;
}



void OpenGlVideoQtQuick::sync()
{
    if (!openGlVideoQtQuickRenderer) {
        openGlVideoQtQuickRenderer = new OpenGlVideoQtQuickRenderer();
        connect(window(), &QQuickWindow::beforeRendering, openGlVideoQtQuickRenderer, &OpenGlVideoQtQuickRenderer::render, Qt::DirectConnection);
        connect(window(), &QQuickWindow::afterRendering, this, &OpenGlVideoQtQuick::update, Qt::DirectConnection);
    } 
    this->openGlVideoQtQuickRenderer->qQuickVideoMatrix = getModelMatrix();
}

static const GLfloat ver[] = {
    -1.0f,-1.0f,
     1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f,
     1.0f, 1.0f
};

static const GLfloat tex[] = {
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f
};


void OpenGlVideoQtQuickRenderer::render()
{
    if (this->firstRun) {
        std::cout << "Creating QOpenGLShaderProgram " << std::endl;
        this->firstRun = false;
        program = new QOpenGLShaderProgram();
        initializeOpenGLFunctions();

        std::cout << "Fragment Shader compilation: " << program->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, tString2) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Vertex Shader compilation: " << program->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, vString2) << std::endl;

        program->bindAttributeLocation("vertexIn",A_VER);
        program->bindAttributeLocation("textureIn",T_VER);
        std::cout << "program->link() = " << program->link() << std::endl;

        glGenTextures(3, texs);//TODO: ERASE THIS WITH glDeleteTextures
    }
    program->bind();
    program->setUniformValue("u_transform", this->qQuickVideoMatrix);


    //glViewport(50, 50, 50, 50);

    glVertexAttribPointer(A_VER, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, ver);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(A_VER);

    glVertexAttribPointer(T_VER, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, tex);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(T_VER);

    unis[0] = program->uniformLocation("tex_y");
    unis[1] = program->uniformLocation("tex_u");
    unis[2] = program->uniformLocation("tex_v");

    //Y
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[0]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, width, height, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    //U
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[1]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, width/2, height / 2, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    //V
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[2]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, width / 2, height / 2, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);



    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,4);

    program->disableAttributeArray(A_VER);
    program->disableAttributeArray(T_VER);
    program->release();

}
```

**OpenGlVideoQtQuick.h**:

```
#ifndef OpenGlVideoQtQuick_H
#define OpenGlVideoQtQuick_H

#include <QtQuick/QQuickItem>
#include <QtGui/QOpenGLShaderProgram>
#include <QtGui/QOpenGLFunctions>
#include <QtQuick/qquickwindow.h>
#include <QtGui/QOpenGLShaderProgram>
#include <QtGui/QOpenGLContext>
#include <QString>
#include <iostream>
#include <QTimer>



class OpenGlVideoQtQuickRenderer : public QObject, protected QOpenGLFunctions
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    OpenGlVideoQtQuickRenderer() {        
    }
    ~OpenGlVideoQtQuickRenderer();
    QMatrix4x4 qQuickVideoMatrix;



public slots:
    void render();

private:
    QOpenGLShaderProgram* program;
    GLuint unis[3] = {0};
    GLuint texs[3] = {0};
    unsigned char *datas[3] = { 0 };
    bool firstRun = true;
    //TODO: make this variable according to video data
    int width = 1920;
    int height = 1080;
};

class OpenGlVideoQtQuick : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    OpenGlVideoQtQuick();
    QMatrix4x4 getModelMatrix();


private slots:
    void handleWindowChanged(QQuickWindow *win);
public slots:
    void sync();
    void update();//Updates the window

private:
    OpenGlVideoQtQuickRenderer *openGlVideoQtQuickRenderer;

};

#endif // OpenGlVideoQtQuick_H
```

**main.qml:**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import OpenGLComponents 1.0
Item {
    width: 1280
    height: 720
    OpenGlVideoQtQuick {
        width: 640
        height: 480

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, your code from Github didn't compile due to some error so I can only assume what it do. So ... don't you have to set `QQuickItem::ItemHasContents` to be sure that your item will be rendered by the scene graph? Why don't you follow the Qt recommendation: _The best rule of thumb is to only use classes with the "QSG" prefix inside the QQuickItem::updatePaintNode() function_? And I really can't find a code where you refer to the item size inside the `update()` function. And I'm not sure that matrix contains the item size ... did you check what `getModelMatrix()` returns?

Comment: @folibis I don't have any idea of what QSG means and how to use it. Do you have an article of some sort? I also didn't know about updatePaintNode and ItemHasContents, I was using the signal `afterRendering`. If you tell me which error you had, I'll fix it. Also, yes, the rendering works. I also don't know how or if the matrix contain the item size, that's one thing I was expecting to be answered. Thank you so much!

Comment: The simple example there is in Qtquickltem [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#updatePaintNode). That's the common way to create visual items in QtQuick. The transform matrix doesn't contain the item size, but only transform types line Rotation, Scale etc. You have to rely on the width() and height() to get the item size.

Comment: @folibis I don't understand this example I'd need a more complete one to look. This doesn't look like it's rendering OpenGL. Anyways, what is the transform() function for QQuickItem then? It gets transformations for what, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question and your code it is a little unclear what you were "expecting" to see but I do see a few issues which might help you:

1. I don't think your render loop is actually called. You must do this in your constructor: `setFlag(ItemHasContents);`
2. Make sure you do pass some texture/video data into your `glTexImage2D()` calls otherwise you will get some garbage (random green garbage?)
3. You may want to have a look at `QQuickItem::widthChanged` and `QQuickItem::heightChanged` signals
4. Make sure you have that `glViewport()` as well as `glClear()` calls when debugging to avoid confusions - you can delete them later when you don't need them anymore

Comment: why glViewport is useful for debugging?

Comment: glViewport() together with glClear() is useful only in the sense that it can help to see/test the regions that must or must not be cleared. It can help distinguish between window, garbage and cleared regions. Just a good starting point for development in my opinion. That’s all.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are outputting Normalized Device coordinates, you should just need to set glViewPort and scissor test to the item's x(), y(), width(), height() (no transform needed on vertices). As far as the green you are seeing, this is because none of your YUV textyres have actual data. As a result, in your pixel shader yuv contains (0, -0.5, -0.5) which when transformed by your YUV to RGB matrix yields rgb(0.0, 0.487625, -1.016055) which is a half intensity green.